# Facebook adding php extension to link

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, google-analytics

We have noticed in our Google analytics that we have a lot of traffic including the php file extension. No link on our page is including the php file extension, and no external links either. It seems like the reason for this problem is when we post our link on Facebook.

We post on Facebook *example.com/page* but it appears in the browser as **example.com/page.php**

We want all links to be without the php extension in order to make google analytics see them as one page. Any ideas?

We are using the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

#remove file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Remove the www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect IP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XX\.XX\.XXX\.XXX
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: for this you have to create specific rules for each page.
E.g RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php [QSA,L]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What is the expected result from this rule? If i write www.example.com/login.php - it does not remove the php file extension. I assume that it will not change the link from the facebook post?

Comment: then you should no need to use login.php - you can just use www.example.com/login and it will redirect you to login.php

Comment: if the only issue is for Google Analytics reports, why not set up a Google Analytics filter on the request URI?